# need to move videos from iphoto to Lacie external hard drive

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

i am on a Macbook air with yosemite 10.10.5 and my video exports fail.

Trying to export it thru Photos menu - select file >  export and choose my to LaCie share external HD but got that error.

[image]

...im able to drag or copy the file to my desktop and from there move it to the external HD but can't do it directly, don't know why. tried to export it to my internal HD but didn't let me either. already looked into this post [How to move all iPhoto video files to an external disk or a NAS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15777/how-to-move-all-iphoto-video-files-to-an-external-disk-or-a-nas?rq=1)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  It would be helpful if you provided additional details such as the OS, devices being used, what steps you've already taken, etc.  Please review [ask] on to format your question to have the best chance at being correctly answered. - From Review -

Comment: Also, please explain how you are you are exporting it, whether it works if you export it to the internal HD/SSD and which previous posts you are refering to?

Comment: Hi, i am on a Macbook air with yosemite 10.10.5...im updating to the latest version...tried to export it thru Photos, file, export and to LaCie share external HD but got that error...im able to drag or copy the file to my desktop and from there move it to the external HD but can't do it directly, don't know why. tried to export it to my internal HD but didn't let me either.

Comment: I've edited this to assume you need to export. Why not just duplicate your entire library to the external and then open it and remove the photos from the second library - leaving what fails to export in the new library. En delete the videos from the main library and empty trash?

Answer (score 1):

You nailed the problem when you tried to export to your desktop instead of the external drive. It's the export process that's broken.

You could pursue two avenues:

1. Dig into the video format of one specific file and work through that here.
2. Contact Apple support since your version of Photos is likely new enough to get support (or free support on twitter would get you the Apple KB that lists what video formats are supported for export.